# How can you define sections with default content in MVC 6?

Tags: view, migration, asp.net-core, extension-methods, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently trying to migrate an ASP.net MVC 5 project to MVC 6.

How would I migrate the following code:

```
public static class SectionExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult RenderSection(this WebPageBase webPage, [RazorSection] string name, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> defaultContents)
    {
        return webPage.IsSectionDefined(name) ? webPage.RenderSection(name) : defaultContents(null);
    }
}
```

[RazorSection] is part of the JetBrains.Annotations assembly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `WebPageBase` I used `RazorPage` in `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor`

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public static class SectionExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlContent RenderSection(this RazorPage page, [RazorSection] string name, Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent> defaultContents)
        {
            return page.IsSectionDefined(name) ? page.RenderSection(name) : defaultContents(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then reference the class in the razor page `@using static Stackoverflow.SessionExtensions`, and call it like so:

```
@this.RenderSection("extra", @<span>This is the default!</span>))
```

An **alternative** way would be to just do this in the view (*I prefer this way, seems a lot simpler*):

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("extra"))
{
    @RenderSection("extra", required: false)
}
else
{
    <span>This is the default!</span>
}
```

I hope this helps.

**Update 1** (from comments)

by referencing the namespace

```
@using Stackoverflow
```

you don't have to include the `static` keyword, but when calling it, you will have to reference the actual class in the namespace and also pass '**this**' into the function.

```
@SectionExtensions.RenderSection(this, "extra", @<span>This is the default!</span>)
```

**Update 2**

There is a bug in razor that does not allow you to call template delegates `Func <dynamic, object> e = @<span>@item</span>;` within a section. Please see https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/672

A current workaround:

```
public static class SectionExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent RenderSection(this RazorPage page, [RazorSection] string name, IHtmlContent defaultContents)
    {
        return page.IsSectionDefined(name) ? page.RenderSection(name) : defaultContents;
    }
}
```

and then the razor page:

```
section test {
    @this.RenderSection("extra", new HtmlString("<span>this is the default!</span>")); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't like the alternative way simply because I like to keep if statements outside of the view.I tried what you mentioned and everything seems to work except for the namespace. It seems as though I have to use: SectionExtensions.RenderSection instead of the this.RenderSection. The using statement doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: I've updated my answer, for some reason my previous edit didn't go through. To reference a static class directly, you will have use the static keyword eg. '@using static Stackoverflow.SessionExtensions', however if you just reference the namespace, you don't have to add static eg. '@using Stackoverflow'. It all depends if you want to include the whole namespace into your view. In that case, you have to call '@SessionExtension.RenderSection' instead of '@this.RenderSection' and also then pass 'this' into the function RenderSection(this, "test", @<span>default</span>). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I thought this was working but I've run into an issue. Lets say you have a nested layout. In the MasterLayout you have a standard @RenderSection("test", false). Then you have a SubMasterLayout that inherits the MasterLayout. If I try 

@section test { 
     @SectionExtensions.RenderSection(this, "extra", @<span>This is the default!</span>)
} 

I get the following exception: '__razor_template_writer': a parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter. 

This worked perfectly in MVC5?

Comment: That is a bug in razor. Basically it creates a parameter method '__razor_template_writer' when calling @section test {} then when you try to create a razor template delegate '@<span>test!</span>' within that section, it creates another parameter method with the same name, hence the bug. Workaround for this could be @SectionExtensions.RenderSection("hello", item => new HtmlString("<span>test</span>")). [..]

Comment: [..] Or you can remove the Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent> from the RenderSection method and just make it IHtmlContent and call it with @SectionExtensions.RenderSection("hello", new HtmlString("<span>test</span>")). This way you would have the same result, just not with calling templates '@<p></p>'. Please see https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/672 I have logged the issue. Please let me know if you have any problems with workaround.